# Is there a way to find which methods were called within a method via reflection?

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a v4.5 C#/.NET application and have to find which methods are dependent on a method. I want to list those methods out.

For example, if I have a method in a class and if this method uses another method:

```
public void Test()
{
    CallMethodA();
    CallMethodB();
}
```

When I pass in method `Test` to my application, I want it to print out CallMethodA and CallMethodB via reflection.

So far I have created this:

```
MethodBase methodBase = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("Test");
var instructions = MethodBodyReader.GetInstructions(methodBase);

foreach (Instruction instruction in instructions)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = instruction.Operand as MethodInfo;

    if(methodInfo != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MethodBodyReader`?

Comment: @mikez - i guess he wants something like that, which tell all the methods that is called within it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but beware of compiler inlining (which would replace, for performance resons,  method-call instruction with the instructions that were in the target method's body).

Comment: @Eve I don't think it's that one because that project has a type called `ILInstruction` not `Instruction` and no static method called `GetInstructions`.

Comment: What you are doing would work fine.  Look for call and callvirt, in the IL stream they will have a metadata token that points to method.  Use the module.resolvexxx methods to get the methodinfo.  Calli for native methods will not have methodinfo I dont think.  You wont see inlining here because that is done by the jit and not the C# compiler

Answer (score 2):

[Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) would be a good place to start. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials) question has lots of tutorials linked in answers.

However, this will only give you static analysis, i.e. the method calls at compile time. If you have method calls to an interface or virtual method then you won't know what other methods are actually being called at run-time. If you want to know what code was actually called at run-time you need to collect coverage information via instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much like creating your own application like [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). If you want to know what calls are made within method of a class, you have to create something like Reflector. Also, do check out [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/); it can be of help.

#### About ILSpy

> ILSpy is the open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler.
>
> Development started after Red Gate announced that the free version of
> .NET Reflector would cease to exist by end of February 2011.